# IWebBrowser2 on CE device cannot navigate to URL

Tags: c++, com, windows-ce

I'm trying to embed a web browser control into a window on a CE 6 application. I can create the web browser control but it fails to load the URL. The code so far is:

```
CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
IWebBrowser2 * pBrowser = NULL; 
HRESULT hr; 

hr = CoCreateInstance (CLSID_WebBrowser, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IWebBrowser2, (void **) &pBrowser);

if (SUCCEEDED (hr)) 
{ 
    pBrowser->put_Visible ((VARIANT_BOOL) true);
    VARIANT vEmpty;
    VariantInit(&vEpty);

    BSTR bstrURL = SysAllocString(L"http://microsoft.com");

    hr = pBrowser->Navigate(bstrURL, &vEmpty, &vEmpty, &vEmpty, &vEmpty);

    // ** At this point, hr = E_FAIL
}
else 
{ 
    MessageBox(_T("Could not create browser window"), _T("Error"), MB_OK);
}
```

Why would the call to `Navigate()` return `E_FAIL`?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752133(v=vs.85).aspx Navigate returns three values S_OK , E_INVALIDARG and E_OUTOFMEMORY..

Comment: Wrong version. This is CE. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee487493%28v=winembedded.60%29.aspx - it returns E_INVALIDARG, E_OUTOFMEMORY, E_UNEXPECTED, and E_FAIL

Comment: Have you tried passing in NULL for the parameters instead of untyped, empty VARIANTs?